# Animated div height expanding choppy

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div that expands right under the navbar, pushing the main content under it as it expands. However, for some reason this does not work with keyframes, and I cannot do it with transition, because it has to happen right on page load.

Here's what I got:

```css
.c-lander {
    animation-name: c-lander-intro;
    animation-duration: 900ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes c-lander-intro {
    0% {
        height: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        height: inherit;
    }
}

.c-lander {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background: #01C9B6;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div class="c-lander">Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height </div>
Here is the content that gets pushed
```

As you can see, the div has a 2 frame animation instead of a smooth 60fps one. 
What is going on here?

Comment: take a look at this [ http://jsfiddle.net/maio/02hxxgv9/1/ ] , it's not complete but may point the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't animate height to `auto` (what this `inherit` resolves to).  An alternative is to animate `max-height` with a set value.

```css
.c-lander {
    animation-name: c-lander-intro;
    animation-duration: 900ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes c-lander-intro {
    0% {
        max-height: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        max-height: 300px;
    }
}

.c-lander {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background: #01C9B6;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div class="c-lander">Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height </div>
Here is the content that gets pushed
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed! Only issue is that too much of a max-height makes the animation inaccurate in speed and ease.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen if you want it perfect, you probably have to use js. This is about as good as you can get it in CSS :D

Comment: That is correct.  It's something that you have to either adjust for accordingly, or simply anticipate as going to happen especially for blocks that are particularly small.  If you're content is very diverse in size, I highly recommend some minimal javascript to accomodate.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a unit for it to animate to, `inherit` doesn't work correctly:

```
@keyframes c-lander-intro {
    0% {
        height: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/02hxxgv9/)

Note: you have to add browser prefixes for this to work in all browsers

Comment: The div has variable height depending on each page, so what can I use instead of inherit?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.c-lander {
    animation-name: c-lander-intro;
    animation-duration: 900ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes c-lander-intro {
    0% {
        height: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100px;
    }
}

.c-lander {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background: #01C9B6;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div class="c-lander">Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height. Here is some text that is very texty and is supposed to demonstrate and give this div a height </div>
Here is the content that gets pushed
```

css animations do not like inheret. Try using a fixed height.